# Ajax POST is only excuting php script on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a canvas element to collect users signature, I then have a button with an onclick function to save the signature to the server, this runs an ajax script to POST the data to a php file.
The problem I have is that although the data gets saved, i have to click the button and then do a page refresh for the save event to actually occur. 
Please help me to see where I've gone wrong as I don't wan tto have to do a manual refresh.
The code is below.

Canvas HTML element:

```
  <div class="signature-pad--body">
     <canvas id="signCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="signature-pad--footer">
     <div class="description">Sign above</div>
         <div class="signature-pad--actions">
              <div>
                <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
                <button type="button" class="button" data-action="undo">Undo</button>
              </div>
              <div>
              <input type="button" class="button save" onclick="signUploader()" id="signReady" value="Upload above Signature" />
              </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

JS Ajax script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
   function signUploader() {
   // Generate the image data

   var pic = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
   pic = "data="+pic;
   console.log(pic); //just for seeing that it's working
      $.ajax({
          url: "includes/signSave.php",
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
          dataType: "text", 
          data: pic ,                   
          beforeSend : function() {
            $("#signCanvas").fadeOut(); }
      });
    }
 </script>
```

signSave.php

```
 <?php

   $img = $_POST['data'];
   $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
   $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
   $fileData = base64_decode($img);
   $file = '../../uploads/signature' . time() . '.png';
   file_put_contents($file, $fileData);
?>
```

This is my first time playing with ajax, so please help me out, and explain if there are errors in there.
Thanks

Comment: well you do nothing with the ajax request when it completes. You send the data and that is it.

Comment: @epascarello so what do I need to add? do I need a complete or success action? what would i put in a complete or success function?

Comment: I do not know since I have no clue what you are expecting to happen. Add a success/done method and do what you want with it.

Comment: @epascarello if i add a success element woould that be enough to trigger the save to occur without a refresh of the page?

Comment: @TCarter Can you give some details how does your page looks after refresh? Also it would be great if you could indicate markup where you want to show desire output.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should return true from `signSave.php` and in success, you can reload the page like below.

```
 'success' : function(data) {              
                window.location.reload();
            }
```

Comment: I've just tried this, without the ' ' around success, but still have to do a manual refresh for the save to occur?
(It didn't work at all with the ' ' )

Comment: so end of PHP now looks like:  
return true;
?>
and ajax:
data: pic ,                   
beforeSend : function() {
$("#signCanvas").fadeOut(); },
success : function(data) {              
window.location.reload();
}

Comment: Just found my console was causing a pause on refresh.
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

add

> location.reload();

to refresh page after your ajax , since you are not returning anything to ajax

Comment: I've just tried that:
beforeSend : function() {
$("#signCanvas").fadeOut(); };
});
location.reload();
}
</script>

and now it doesn't save at all!!!

Comment: @TCarter is it refresh page ?

Comment: Just found my console was causing a pause on refresh.
Thanks for all your help.